# What's the hypersolid angle of a 5-cell (4d tetrahedron)?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, simplex, solid-angle

It's known that the solid angle of the vertex of a regular tetrahedron is $\arccos(\frac{23}{27})$, or equivalently, $\frac\pi2-3\arcsin(\frac13)$ or $3\arccos(\frac13)-\pi$. (Trig identities are weird.) This is around $0.551$ steradians, or around $0.044$ times the whole sphere.

What about the same question but one dimension higher? The 4d equivalent of the tetrahedron is known as the 5-cell, also called the 4-simplex. **What is the hypersolid angle of the regular 5-cell?**

I managed to write some Python code that approximates the solid angle, shown below. It does so by choosing a random point in $\Bbb R^5$ using a spherically symmetric distribution (the normal distribution was easiest) and checking to see if the all coordinates were above average but the last one. The odds of success was then multiplied by the surface volume of the hypersphere (which is $2\pi^2$) to convert to cubic radians. (You can check that the equivalent code one dimension down gives the correct answer for the tetrahedron.) This code is very slow (it takes a minute or two to run) and not very accurate, but it was the best I could think of. The final verdict is that it's around $0.192$ or $0.193$ cubic radians.

```
import numpy as np

many = 10_000_000
count = 0
for i in range(many):
  vec = np.random.normal(size=5)
  avg = np.mean(vec)
  count += (vec[0]>=avg and vec[1]>=avg and vec[2]>=avg and vec[3]>=avg)
result = count/many
print(f"The solid angle of a 5-cell is {round(result,3)} of the full"
  f" hypersphere, or {round(2*np.pi**2*result,3)} radians^3.")
```

`The solid angle of a 5-cell is 0.01 of the full hypersphere, or 0.193 radians^3.`

I tried Googling for the answer but couldn't find anything. Since it's not readily available online, I'm guessing that it might not even have a closed form. If that's the case, I would be satisfied with a numerical answer, to perhaps 10 digits or so. (My Monte Carlo method can't get anywhere close.)

Comment: I believe I could get it if I could solve$$\int\hspace{-0.55em}\iiint_{{\Bbb R_{\ge0}}^4}e^{-\vec v^\top Q\vec v}~{\rm d}^4\vec v$$where $Q=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1&1\\1&2&1&1\\1&1&2&1\\1&1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$ but I couldn't see how to do it. There seem to be ways to find the integrals of generalized Gaussians over _all_ of space, but not over a single orthant (the higher-dimensional equivalent of an octant).

Comment: This isn't much progress, but I can extend your Monte Carlo simulations with some tricks to get better data. By using vectorized operations rather than a for loop we can go a fair bit faster, and by counting every time that exactly 1 or 4 of the coordinates exceed the average we can see ten times as many events without double-counting anything. After ten billion samples, this gives a frequency whose 95% confidence interval is roughly $[0.00978407, 0.00978527]$.